# Mysql current date trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have the following trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER `qc_date_trigger` AFTER UPDATE ON `brand`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    IF NEW.brandQC = '1' THEN
        SET @brandQCDate = CURDATE();
    ELSE
        SET @brandQCDate = NULL;
    END IF;


 END
```

For some reason it does not update my Date field into the current date when QC is = 1. I've checked the mysql doc and it should work. Any ideeas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your column is named brandQCDate, then remove the `@`. The `@` makes it a user defined variable, not the column. Also you want to make this a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `qc_date_trigger` BEFORE UPDATE ON `brand`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    IF NEW.brandQC = '1' THEN
        SET NEW.brandQCDate = CURDATE();
    ELSE
        SET NEW.brandQCDate = NULL;
    END IF;


 END
```